# Android camera that records accelerometer/gyroscope information

Tags: android, photography, camera, modeling, gopro

For [photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry), it would be helpful to know the orientation of the camera when the photo was taken.

For videos in which the camera was rotated during filming, it would be good to know which way was down, so that the rotation can be corrected later (instead of viewers tilting their heads).

There aren't any standard EXIF tags for this purpose, unfortunately, but [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#Technical) that you can use GPSImgDirection tag along with custom GPSPitch and GPSRoll tags.  There may be other solutions, too.

Alternatively, maybe it could store the [GPMF information](https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser) that GoPro cameras store.  There are apparently [many other types of metadata](https://exiftool.org/#JPEG) that can be attached to images, maybe some of those contain orientation info, too.

Are there any Android cameras that capture this information in videos and photos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open Camera](https://opencamera.org.uk/) has these options under **Settings** → **Location settings…**

- Store compass direction
- Store yaw, pitch, and roll

It gets saved in the EXIF as

```
User comment                     : Yaw:88.52357,Pitch:-13.394803909474904,Roll:-1.5024806653302676 
Img Direction                    : 2213/25
Img Direction Ref                : M
```

or as exifinfo.org prints it:

```
GPS Img Direction
    88.52
GPS Img Direction Ref
    Magnetic North
User Comment
    Yaw:88.52357,Pitch:-13.394803909474904,Roll:-1.5024806653302676
```

[Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy) pointed out that there is a fork called [OpenCamera Sensors](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.opencamera_extended.app) which disables audio recording and adds gyroscope and accelerometer data as CSV files in a folder for each recording.  (Sometimes it doesn't work on my phone, though, I just get "serious camera error".)

Comment: So what is it missing that [OpenCamera Sensors](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.opencamera_extended.app) adds? Just wondering…

Comment: @Izzy What do you mean?

Comment: I just found that app recently. It says being a fork of Open Camera adding sensor recording. Now you show Open Camera does that itself – and I wonder why it then needed that fork. I've not tried it myself, I'm just curious. If you don't know either, I can cleanup comments and rewrite mine as suggestion to check if it records additional data.

Comment: @Izzy Oh I see.  I was experimenting with Open Camera and it will record GPS coordinates and compass direction along with video as subtitles, but I don't see a way to save orientation information for videos, only for photos.  You should post OpenCamera Sensors as a separate answer.

Comment: I can't as I never used it myself – so I cannot really tell how well it matches or what it does in addition. As it's a (supposedly enhanced) fork, it might be an extension to your answer; feel free to integrate it or post a second answer if you think it is useful. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/MobileRoboticsSkoltech/OpenCamera-Sensors